# Confusion about jQuery UI transfer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to use jQuery UI `transfer()` method to hide an element.

I have a `div.click` and a `span.target`. I want the `div` to be moved to the `span` when clicked.

I tried this code:

```
$("div.click").live('click', function () {
      var i = 1 - $("div.click").index(this);
      $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $("span.target").eq(i) }, 1000);
});
```

but nothing happens.

In the demo I downloaded it was said that `transfer` is an option of "hide". But on their site it says its an option of "effect".

Could someone help me understand how to use this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Transfer) (which was rather [difficult to find](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Types)) you must style the `ui-effects-transfer` class (typically specifying a dashed border) in order to see the transfer in the first place.

The documentation of the `hide()` method is somewhat misleading though, you cannot use the `"transfer"` effect with `hide()`. However, if you do want to make the element invisible after the `"transfer"` effect is complete, you can use a callback as I've done in the following demo.

**Working Demo:** http://jsbin.com/iwijo (editable via http://jsbin.com/iwijo/edit)

P.S. I'm assuming that `1 -` in your code was intentional and not a typo. Passing a negative index to `eq()` makes it select elements in reverse order.

Answer (score 2):

instead of chaining one may rather use a function callback - in order to make it happen just when the transfer finshed:

```
$("div.click").live('click', function () {
   var i = 1 - $("div.click").index(this);
   $(this).effect('transfer', { to: $("span.target").eq(i) }, 1000, function(){
      $(this).hide();
   });
});
```

(I used it like this to attach an image instead.)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Transfer) states

> Transfers the outline of an element to
>   another element

So, no hiding is involved here.

If you do want to hide the element, all you have to do is chain the `hide()` function after your effect:

```
$("div.click").live('click', function () {
      var i = 1 - $("div.click").index(this);
      $(this).effect("transfer", { to: $("span.target").eq(i) }, 1000).hide();
});
```

Please not - I did **Not** test your code - I just added the hide section, so I'm not sure it work :)